# Elegoo "Uno R3" not being recognized in any computer anymore

Tags: clones

I used to be able to use my Elegoo Uno R3, just fine. It worked with my computer no problem. Except I used the USB cable on a power bank and now the Uno isn't being recognized on any computer. I tried uninstalling and re-installing the IDE and drivers. But nothing works. I don't even get the serial 2.0 USB in the device manager. the Uno itself works. The orange and green lights stay on continuously when plugged in and It's still outputting the code I put in it before it stopped connecting to my computer. Any help to be able to fix my Uno. The button on the UNO doesn't seem to do anything either.

Comment: Worth trying a different cable, but likely you've damaged it.  That power bank should be considered suspect, and probably not used again with anything you value.

Comment: I did try a different cable but no luck